# Pandas DataFrame keep earliest column with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am consuming dataframes of demographics data on a NUTS3 level and different regions report data at different time intervals. I always want the newest data, the year varies from region to region.

Data might look like below
|

```
region|2015|2014|2013|
AT201 | 101| 100|    |
AB301 |    | 123| 456|
AB302 |    |    | 234|
```

How can I combine year columns into a single column holding the newest data, like

```
region|newest_data|
AT201 |        101|
AB301 |        123| 
AB302 |        234|
```

Below a link to screenshot of actual data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUP3A.png

Any tips or pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert not years columns to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), back filling missing values, select first column, rename it and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.set_index(['region']).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].rename('newest_data').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you kindly jezrael - this worked like a charm. I am not able to up-vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation, but I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: @RasmusLehmann - In future ;) Happy coding!